# Thank you for explaning me

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Should we say this sentence when they are done expalining me, or while they are explaining, or when they are about to start explaining?

For example, a professor has done his explanation. Can I say thanks to the professor for explaining this to me?

Comment: You can thank someone for explaining something **to** you. Don't say _explaining me_, because that would mean explaining _about_ you.

Answer (score 1):

The object of the verb "explain" is the thing the professor is talking about.  So unless the professor is explaining how your mind works this is not correct!

Instead, you can say "Thanks for explaining that to me."  The pronoun "that" refers to the topic that has been explained.

It would be odd to say "Thanks" before or during the explanation.  But you can ask  "Could you please explain {something} to me?".  Obviously don't interrupt someone to say thanks while they are talking!

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it.